# How to append output of preg_match to an existing array?

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-match

I have two preg_match() calls and i want to merge the arrays instead of replacing the first array. my code so far:

```
$arr = Array();
$string1 = "Article: graphics card";
$string2 = "Price: 300 Euro";
$regex1 = "/Article[\:] (?P<article>.*)/";
$regex2 = "/Price[\:] (?P<price>[0-9]+) Euro/";

preg_match($regex1, $string1, $arr);
//output here:
$arr['article'] = "graphics card"
$arr['price'] = null
preg_match($regex2, $string2, $arr);
//output here:
$arr['article'] = null
$arr['price'] = "300"
```

How may I match so my output will be:

```
$arr['article'] = "graphics card"
$arr['price'] = "300"
```

?

Comment: You could merge the matching logic for the two regex and then preg_match a concatenated version of the strings.

Comment: Mind using a `$cache=array();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `preg_replace_callback` and handle the merging inside the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me this is how I would do it, this would allow for easier extension at a later date, and would avoid using a callback function. It could also support searching one string easily by replacing `$strs[$key]` and the `$strs` array with a singular string var. It doesn't remove the numerical keys, but if you are only ever to go on accessing the associative keys from the array this will never cause a problem.

```
$strs = array();
$strs[] = "Article: graphics card";
$strs[] = "Price: 300 Euro";

$regs = array();
$regs[] = "/Article[\:] (?P<article>.*)/";
$regs[] = "/Price[\:] (?P<price>[0-9]+) Euro/";

$a = array();

foreach( $regs as $key => $reg ){
  if ( preg_match($reg, $strs[$key], $b) ) {
    $a += $b;
  }
}

print_r($a);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Article: graphics card
    [article] => graphics card
    [1] => graphics card
    [price] => 300
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) for this if you store your results in two different arrays.
But your output depicted above is not correct. You do not have $arr['price'] if you search with regex1 in your string but only $arr['article']. Same applies for the second preg_match.
That means if you store one result in $arr and one in $arr2 you can merge them into one array.

preg_match does not offer the functionality itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use different array for second preg_match ,say  `$arr2`
2. Traverse `$arr2` as `$key => $value` .
3. Choose non null value out of   `$arr[$key]` and `$arr2[$key]`, and write that value to `$arr[$key]`.
4. `$arr` will have required merged array.

Answer (score -1):

This should work for your example:

```
array_merge( // selfexplanatory
           array_filter( preg_match($regex1, $string1, $arr)?$arr:array() ), //removes null values
           array_filter( preg_match($regex2, $string2, $arr)?$arr:array() ) 
  );
```

Comment: `preg_match()` returns integer (or `FALSE` in case of error), so `array_filter()` on it will not work.